# How to trigger click event without $refs in vue?

Tags: vue.js, contenteditable

I have template like this:

```html
<p @click="handleParagraphClick">
    <component v-for="item in items" :is="spanComponent"/>
</p>
```

Template of nested span component is like this:

```html
<span @click="handleSpanClick">{{content}}</span>
```

Paragraph component is rendered inside contenteditable div.

When I click on paragraph I want to trigger click event on span within `handleParagraphClick`.

(When I click on paragraph I want to put caret into span and mark span as current active node which can be done by calling `handleSpanClick` but this is another story.)

It could be done using

```js
this.$refs.mySpan.click()
```

but I haven't `$refs` on spans. How can I do it without `$refs`?

**Upd.**

(When I click on the empty place of the paragraph I want to put caret at the end of the last span and trigger click event for that span. When I click between spans I want to put caret at the beginning of the right span (or at the end of the left span).)

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple spans as dynamic components. In which one are you planning on call the **handleSpanClick** method?
You still can use $refs in v-for to access an array of components like this:

```
<p @click="handleParagraphClick"><component v-for="item in items" :is="spanComponent" refs="spans"/></p>
```

code:

```
const mySpan = this.$refs.spans[0] // get the first span for instance
mySpan.handleSpanClick()
```

Comment: I need to know clicked span index in such case to use it in `$refs.spans[]`.

Comment: In your question you said that you click a paragraph and not a span. So that means you trigger a click event on the paragraph but not on the span. On the other hand if you click on a span that will lead to trigger a click event on the span itself. Please clarify what you wish to achieve.

Comment: Anatoly, you are right. When I click on the empty place of the paragraph I want to put caret at the end of the last span and trigger click event for that span. When I click between spans I want to put caret at the beginning of the right span (or at the end of the left span). I missed that part.

Comment: The first case with the last span wouldn't be a problem. The problem is to determine sibling spans around click position. Can you add some elements between spans to catch clicks and to determine spans that are next to the clicked element?

Comment: Anatoly, there is another issue. I have attached `@click` to the root element of component. If I trigger click event by `$refs.spans[]` which is related to the component will it be triggered?

Comment: just call event handler directly in a child component.